# vue-draggableで作成したリストをドラッグすると他の要素のbackgroundが変わる

Tags: javascript, vue.js

[vue-draggable](https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable) で作成したドラッグ可能なリスト(ul,liタグ)を、ulタグ以外の場所にドロップすると、別のdiv要素のbackground-colorが変更されてしまいます。
ul,liタグに背景色をつければdiv要素の背景色が変更されることはありません。
ウィンドウサイズを変更したり、もう一度ドラッグするなど別のイベントを発生すると元に戻るようです。
この挙動についてわかる方いらっしゃいませんでしょうか。

再現デモ： [https://codesandbox.io/s/n3k2py9mll](https://codesandbox.io/embed/n3k2py9mll)
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]